# Unity приложение поверх всех окон

Tags: c#, windows, unity3d

Вопрос, есть ли возможность через код (c# script) задать установку, что бы **полноэкранное** окно приложения Unity всегда было над другими окнами **при запуске**.
ОС Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот вариант с использованием WinAPI:

```cs
private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
SetWindowPos(GetActiveWindow(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

SetWindowPos более подробно: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos

Обратите внимание что получение дескриптора окна идет через получение активного окна, по этому убедитесь что оно активно или сделайте его таковым.

Второй вариант получения дескриптора окна через FindWindow метод:

```cs
private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

IntPtr windowHwnd = FindWindow("class", "caption");

private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
SetWindowPos(windowHwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

За частую в FindWindow class и caption можно просто написать заголовок окна, но если это не так -- воспользуйтесь утилитой Spy++ которая комплектуется с Visual Studio 2015 и младше.

Comment: использовали 1 способ, работает, спасибо